# Run command script that is not in package.json using yarn

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, lerna

How can I run a script that is not available in `package.json`?

Everything works fine if I execute:

```
yarn run build
```

And my `package.json` contains the build script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  }
}
```

But I get an error if I execute directly:

```
yarn run rollup -c // ERROR: Command \"rollup -c\" not found
```

I need to execute commands **using the environment variables** available to the scripts at runtime of `yarn run <script>`.

Is there any syntax Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `yarn run build` it will look for a `build` script inside your package.json scripts section.

When you are running `yarn run rollup -c` it is looking for `rollup` which doesn't exist inside your package.json.

If you want to run `rollup -c` do it without `yarn run` and it should work.

Comment: I think that `rollup` should be sctrictly global to work using `rollup -c`. My package is not installed globally.

Comment: If `rollup` is inside your node_modules folder, you can always add your local node_modules to the PATH variable assuming you have a MAC

```export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"```

Comment: Yeah but Im looking for a way to run "custom commands" in the "yarn enviroment". Maybe its not possible

Comment: It seems that `yarn run` add "./node_mudles/.bin" to the path automatically. However, `rollup` may not be added to that folder. So you cannot always run `yarn run xxx` directly in cli when you were able to run it by adding it to the `package.json` file.